# Angular - Correct way to modify DOM elements in a Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a directive, powerEntry, with varying CSS classes I'd like to add/remove based on model state.

Currently, I have a link function, with some logic like this:

**Script.JS**

```
  if (calcState.availablePoints > 0 && isHighEnoughLevel) {
    levelUpBtnClass = 'enabled';
  } else if (calcState.availablePoints === 0 ) { // TODO: If ability is at cap, also disabled.
    levelUpBtnClass = 'disabled';
  }

  if (power.currentRank<=1) {
    powerRankClass = 'standard';
  } else {
    powerRankClass = 'enhanced';
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="powerIcon" ng-src="/images/heroes/{{hero.name}}/powers/{{power.iconSrc}}">
<span class="powerRank" ng-class="powerRankClass">{{power.currentRank}}</span>
<div class="levelUpBtn" ng-class="levelUpBtnClass"></div>
```

While this implementation is functional, I don't know if it's *correct*. It seems that ng-class does take ternary operators, but I feel like putting a complex JS expression in my HTML is the wrong approach.

Is there a best approach here? Are there performance implications to one way or the other?

Comment: I would have come up with something similar to what you implemented, so I'm curious if anyone has knowledge of a preferred solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to complicate your HTML, I suggest adding the classes through the linking function programatically.

The linking function accepts the element so you can do something like:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    //...

    if (power.currentRank<=1) {
        element.addClass('standard');
    } else {
        element.addClass('enhanced');
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: That's actually where the if/else addClass stuff is currently. I just wasn't sure if that was the best approach over some sort of ng-class

Comment: Yes but you can additionally add the classes in that logic and avoid using `ng-class` completely.

Answer (score 0):

This is really where you should use `ngClass` it can take expressions.

Therefore you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
 ng-class="{enhanced: powerRankClass > 1, standard: powerRankClass == 1}"
```

If you set up a jsfiddle, I can get it all working for you.